# Page redirect after handling global exception

Tags: c#, razor, abp

I'm working on learning the Abp framework and in my project I am using a third party REST service that requires authentication and the session can expire.  I found the documentation on handling exceptions:

https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Exception-Handling

and have implemented a subscriber where I find my custom exception that I'm throwing when I detect a session has expired.  I'm using the same username/password for my site as the third party account so I need to send the user back to the login page if the REST session expires.  I tried to do something crazy like this in the .Application project

```
internal class GlobalRedirector : ControllerBase {
    internal IActionResult RedirectToLogin() {
        return RedirectToPage("/Account/Login");
    }
    public class GlobalExceptionSubscriber : ExceptionSubscriber {
        public override async Task<IActionResult> HandleAsync(ExceptionNotificationContext context) {
            if (context.Exception is RestSessionExpiredException) {
                var redirector = new GlobalRedirector();
                return redirector.RedirectToLogin();
            }
            return new OkResult();
        }
    }
}
```

I debugged with some breakpoint and find that The RedirectToLogin method is executing but doesn't work, it's like the Abp framework is swallowing the exception and handling it how it wants.  I tested the Redirect from a normal pages OnGet and it does work... Is there anyway to get a redirect to work when handling a global exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code just creates an RedirectOjbectResult and does nothing else.

You have to inject `IHttpContextAccessor` and add a redirect to response of HttpContext.

```cs
public class MyExSubscriber : ExceptionSubscriber
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public MyExSubscriber(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(ExceptionNotificationContext context)
    {
        // do your stuff.

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/account/login");
    }
}
```